# Subtracting off background data from my data sets

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I don't know how to subtract off background data `Data0` from my data sets collected in `Datagen`.

```
Dimensions[Data0]
```

> ```
> {141}
> ```

```
Dimensions[Datagen]
```

> ```
> {3 , 141}
> ```

I want to subtract the values of `Data0` to each element in `Datagen`.

When I typed

```
Datagen - Data0
```

I got:

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrived test data

```
SeedRandom[42]; background = RandomReal[1, 14]
```

> ```
> {0.425905, 0.391023, 0.347069, 0.453741, 0.555963, 0.289169, 0.296848, 
>  0.206408, 0.32517, 0.973325, 0.258796, 0.550582, 0.717287, 0.754353}
> ```

```
data = Table[i j, {i, 3}, {j, 14}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
>  {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28}, 
>  {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42}}
> ```

We now map a subtraction of the background across the data.

```
# - background & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{0.574095, 1.60898, 2.65293, 3.54626, 4.44404, 5.71083, 6.70315, 
>   7.79359, 8.67483, 9.02668, 10.7412, 11.4494, 12.2827, 13.2456}, 
>  {1.57409, 3.60898, 5.65293, 7.54626, 9.44404, 11.7108, 13.7032, 
>   15.7936, 17.6748, 19.0267, 21.7412, 23.4494, 25.2827, 27.2456}, 
>  {2.57409, 5.60898, 8.65293, 11.5463, 14.444, 17.7108, 20.7032, 
>   23.7936, 26.6748, 29.0267, 32.7412, 35.4494, 38.2827, 41.2456}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seemed very easy but it wasn't for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With m_goldberg's setup, using `Subtract[#, background]` instead of  `# - background &` improves the speed for large inputs:

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
background = RandomReal[1, 100000];
data = Table[i j, {i, 3}, {j, 100000}];

r1 = # - background & /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.001973

```
r2 = Subtract[#, background] & /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming  // First
```

> 0.001137

```
r1 == r2
```

> True

Comment: +1 for `Subtract`. I did know about `Divide` but didn't realized that `Subtract` also improves performance.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful as my program gets finished I will start working with {20 , 141} dimensions